# Find file saved from windows live mail

Tags: excel, file, windows-live-mail

I use windows live mail. Sometimes I get attachments in
Word, Excel, etc. If I open the document from mail, and hit "save" I can not
find out where it saves. It does not save in any temp file that I can see.

Can anyone please tell me if i can ever get those saved files ?

Please note that this happens when i hit only save.

Comment: In the `File` tab, check the "Info" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel File, Open attachment again in Excel from Windows Live Mail.Then I found file location here :

File>Info>Related Documents>Open File Location.

In my case it was on "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\A605094L"

By default this file location will be hidden so you can not find it directly.